# Providing Concurrency Between Pthreads

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, posix

I am working on multithread programming and I am stuck on something.

In my program there are two tasks and two types of robots for carrying out the tasks:

- Task 1 requires any two types of robot and
- task 2 requires 2 robot1 type and 2 robot2 type.

Total number of robot1 and robot2 and pointers to these two types are given for initialization. Threads share these robots and robots are reserved until a thread is done with them.

Actual task is done in  `doTask1(robot **)` function which takes pointer to a robot pointer as parameter so I need to pass the robots that I reserved. I want to provide concurrency. Obviously if I lock everything it will not be concurrent. robot1 is type of Robot **. Since It is used by all threads before one thread calls doTask or finish it other can overwrite robot1 so it changes things. I know it is because robot1 is shared by all threads. Could you explain how can I solve this problem? I don't want to pass any arguments to thread start routine.

`rsc` is my struct to hold number of robots and pointers that are given in an initialization function.

```
void *task1(void *arg)
{
    int tid;
    tid = *((int *) arg);
    cout << "TASK 1 with thread id " << tid << endl;

    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexUpdateRob);
    while (rsc->totalResources < 2)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&noResource, &mutexUpdateRob);
    }

    if (rsc->numOfRobotA > 0 && rsc->numOfRobotB > 0)
    {
        rsc->numOfRobotA --;
        rsc->numOfRobotB--;
        robot1[0] = &rsc->robotA[counterA];
        robot1[1] = &rsc->robotB[counterB];
        counterA ++;
        counterB ++;
        flag1 = true;
        rsc->totalResources -= 2;
    }

     pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexUpdateRob);
     doTask1(robot1);

     pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexUpdateRob);

     if(flag1)
     {
         rsc->numOfRobotA ++;
         rsc->numOfRobotB++;
         rsc->totalResources += 2;
      }

       if (totalResource >= 2)
       {
           pthread_cond_signal(&noResource);
       }
       pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexUpdateRob);

       pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Could you formatt your code better? It is hard to read the way it is showing up.

Comment: It doesn't let me use indentation that's why it is like that

Comment: What doesn't like you use indentation? SO certainly does let you use indentation. (Sure, you can't use tabs; it's a webform.) I've intended it for you, if my edit is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If robots are global resources, threads should not dispose of them. It should be the duty of the main thread exit (or cleanup) function.
Also, there sould be a way for threads to locate unambiguously the robots, and to lock their use.

The `robot1` array seems to store the robots, and it seems to be a global array. However:

- its access is not protected by a mutex (`pthread_mutex_t`), it seems now that you've taken care of that.
- Also, the code in `task1` is always modifying entries `0` and `1` of this array. If two threads or more execute that code, the entries will be overwritten. I don't think that it is what you want. How will that array be used afterwards?

In fact, why does this array need to be global?

The bottom line is this: as long as this array is shared by threads, they **will** have problems working concurrently. Think about it this way:

You have two companies using robots to work, but they're using the same truck (`robot1`) to move the robots around. How are these two companies supposed to function *properly*, and *efficiently* with only one truck?

Comment: Actually I don't need to allocate memory for robots. An array of robota and an array of robotb is passed to me by a function. I just need to use them. However, doTask1 takes pointer to an array with length 2 that contains robots to be used by the thread. I don't know how I can reserve this robots and how can I pass those to doTask so that other threads do not overwrite the argument array that I passed to doTask?

Comment: Yes, as long as they share it, there will be problem but if I do everything in lock then it is not concurrent. I am not familiar with thread programming and I don't know how I can provide concurrency here.Any idea?